# how to click on 'new <div>' which newly generates after clicking on a button? in C# selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, phantomjs

before i clicking the button, the html code for the page is below

```
<div id="layerContainer"> </div>
```

[but after clicking a button, than the code appears like picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbkNq.gif)

I tried to find the new button, but always "unable to find element ~@" ]

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@id='layerContainer']/div/section/div/div[2]/form/article/footer/div/button")));
IWebElement submit2 = this.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='layerContainer']/div/section/div/div[2]/form/article/footer/div/button"));
submit2.Click();
```

my purpose is to find out the newly generated button and click on it,
but it fails to find out the new button all the time, is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Can you show screenshot of this element on the web site ?

Comment: yop, screenshot is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbkNq.gif
and those <div >DBandJoinfromView are the elements generated after clciking a button

Comment: there was only <div id= layercontainer></div> element before clciking a button, the highlighted line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the button according to the coordinates.

For example:

[image]

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("layerContainer")), 97, 272).Click().Perform();
```

Maybe this method will help you.