# How To Draw On a HTML Canvas Image Using C# Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, canvas, drawing

I need to automate a test of HTML Canvas using C# with Selenium WebDriver.  When this test is done manually, it is done by holding a mouse click down and moving the cursor over the image.  Below is the code I've tried so far.  This does not draw on the image.  However, after running this test and stopping at the image, if I manually move the mouse over the image without clicking, it draws on the HTML Canvas.

```
        IWebElement canvasContainer = WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("canvas-container"));                   

        System.Drawing.Point Location = canvasContainer.Location;

        System.Drawing.Size Space = canvasContainer.Size;

        Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriver);            

        builder.ClickAndHold();

        IAction drawAction = builder.MoveToElement(canvasContainer,   

        Location.X, Location.Y) //start points x axis and y axis.

            .ClickAndHold()

            .MoveByOffset(Location.X, Location.Y)
            .ClickAndHold()
            .MoveByOffset(-Location.Y, -Location.Y)

            .ClickAndHold()
            .MoveByOffset(-Location.Y, -Location.Y)

            .ClickAndHold()
            .Build();
        drawAction.Perform();
        int move1 = Space.Width / 2;
        int move2 = Space.Height / 2;
        builder.MoveToElement(canvasContainer, move1, move2);
```

Comment: Can you look this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220377/how-to-click-on-new-div-which-newly-generates-after-clicking-on-a-button-in/40232966#40232966

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a try and I'm still not seeing any drawrings on my image.  It works manually by click and hold, not by click-move-click.  Do you know a way to modify to do a click and hold?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates are probably outside of the canvas since you are adding the location of the canvas as an offset. Try with an offset relative to the element:

```
var canvas = WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("canvas-container"));                   
var size = canvas.Size;

new Actions(WebDriver)
  .MoveToElement(canvas, 2, 2)
  .ClickAndHold()
  .MoveByOffset(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2)
  .Release()
  .Perform();
```